# Запись данных в бд php

Tags: php

Тестирую с помощью строки http://example.com/create_route.php?route_name=cada&route_description=asdasdfgdg
Выдаёт ошибку

> {"success":0,"message":"Required field(s) is missing"}

```
$response = array();

if (isset($_POST['route_name']) && isset($_POST['route_description'])) {

    $route_name = $_POST['route_name'];
    $route_description = $_POST['route_description'];

    require 'db_connect.php';

    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO routes(route_name, route_description) VALUES('.$route_name.', '.$route_description.')");

    if ($result) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Route successfully created.";

        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас видимо проблема с кавычками:

```
...VALUES('".$route_name."', '".$route_description."')"
```

or

```
VALUES($route_name, $route_description)"
```